# Don't create the object if a condition isn't verfied

Tags: python, oop

Can you stop the `__init__` function if a condition isn't verified?
My goal is to avoid creating overlapping sequences, each sequence object I create is of length 4.

```
class Sequence:

    def __init__(self, lastsequence, start, end):
        if start <= lastsequence.end+1:
            #don't create the object and set end of the lastsequence to start+4
        self.start = start 
        self.end = end
```

Comment: You could raise an exception

Comment: The new instance has already been created when `__init__` runs - you could implement `__new__`, and/or throw an error as @khelwood suggests.

Comment: How and where in your code are you creating the sequences?

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew __new__.

Comment: @ReutSharabani when i found a pattern in a matrix i create a new sequence and I don't want them to overlap. But my code is quite long that why I didn't post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you have something like:

```
squence = Sequence(lastsequence, start, end)
```

Change it to:

```
if (start <= lastsequence.end + 1):
    sequence = Sequence(lastsequence, start, end)
```

This way you avoid the construction of a new object completely.